# How to get the gradient potential in polar coordinate

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, differentiation

In polar coordinate,

$$\nabla U = \frac{\partial U}{\partial r}\hat{\mathbf{r}} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial U}{\partial \theta}\hat{\mathbf{\theta}} .$$

Can anyone show me how to get this result?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're working in two dimensions, with Cartesian coordinates $x,y$, the result is obtained by starting with the expression for the gradient in the $x,y$ system:

\begin{align}
\nabla U &= \vec{e}_1 \frac{\partial U}{\partial x} + \vec{e}_2\frac{\partial U}{\partial y},
\end{align}
where $\vec{e}_i$ are the unit vectors in $x (i=1)$ and $y (i=2)$ directions. Then use the transformation between Cartesion and (plane-)polar coordinates:
\begin{align}
x &= r \cos\theta,\\
y &= r \sin\theta,
\end{align}
and the chain rule. For example: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} +
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}$.